# Regex to capture words between a specific word

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to get a regex that matches: (It should not match any other string)

```
Word1 or Word2 or Word3 or Wordn
```

Capturing the words between before or after an "or"

```
1: Word1
2: Word2
3: Word3
n: Wordn
```

I've tried modifying a csv regex:

```
(?:^|,)(\"(?:[^\"]+|\"\")*\"|[^,]*)
```

to

```
(?:^|(?:or)((?:[^(?:or)]+)*|[^(?:or)]*)
```

But that does not give me what I want.

I'm sure I'm missing something, but I've been banging my head for hours.

Comment: I just understood your question better and updated my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
my $string = "  foo or    bar or  foobar ";
if ( $string =~ m|^\s*[^\s]+(\s+or\s+[^\s]+)+\s*$| ) {
    my $tmp = "$string";
    $tmp =~ s|^\s+||;
    $tmp =~ s|\s+$||;
    my @words = split( /\s+or\s+/, $tmp );
    printf( "Found %d words:\n", scalar( @words ) );
    foreach my $word ( @words ) {
        print( "\t'$word'\n" );
    }
} else {
    print( "No match\n" );
}
```

The above will output:

```
Found 3 words:
    'foo'
    'bar'
    'foobar'
```

Comment: I ended up doing a slight variation of this, but the regex was PERFECT!  After I match on the regex, I do the split and pump the results into the array.  THANK!

Comment: @Ron: you could always combine operations for better performance `print($_,"\n") for ( m/^\s*(\S+(?:\s+or\s+\S+)+)\s*$/?split/\s+or\s+/,$1:() );`

Comment: @Wayne Arthurton: His regex VALIDATES each ` or ` be surrounded by a single (1 only) word, where word = any non-whitespace. Your problem explaination sounded a bit different.

Answer (score 1):

Try splitting the string on `' or '`.

Comment: I really need it to be a regex as there are a number of different matching rules that are run against the string.

Comment: How about this: `(.+?)(?: or )|(.+)`. It captures usually into group 1, but the final part into group 2.

Answer (score 1):

You know, this isn't something for which I'd naturally reach for regex. I'd try a split first.

```
my @words = split / or /, $string;
```

Comment: I think I see where you are coming from.  I could detect the Word or Word or Word using a regex and then split on the 'or' once I'm sure it matches.

Answer (score 0):

This regex will match any string that has at least `word1 or word2`, and any number more or's after that. It must have no whitespace at the beginning or end of the string as well, but you can remove the `^` and `$` if you want to search for a string of this form within a larger string

```
(?:^(\w+)(?=\s+or))|(?:\s+or\s+(\w+))+
```

[RegexPal](http://regexpal.com/?flags=&regex=%5E%28?%3a%5Cw%2b%29%28?=%5Cs%2bor%29%28?%3a%5Cs%2bor%5Cs%2b%5Cw%2b%29%2b%24&input=Word1%20or%20Word2%20or%20Word3%20or%20Wordn)

Comment: I need to capture the words between the or.

Comment: Okay, I changed it to be capturing.

Answer (score 0):

The real solution is to split on `' or '`. A regex solution is not so straight forward.

`$sm =~ / or / and @between_or = $sm =~ /(?:^\s*|(?<= or ))(.+?)(?= or |\s*$)/sg;`